# Rewrite the exact url /index.php to /

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect or rewrite an URL but I just can't get it right.

The URL I want to redirect/rewrite is:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php -> http://www.example.com/
```

And only the **exact** ...index.php URL above. Without query string etc.

It's basically just to remove index.php on the start/index page. Enlighten me, please.

**EDIT**

I ended up removing the apache tag after using six tags (I'm new here) so to clarify: I'm using apache.

Comment: Am I an idiot, or doesn't this happen automatically? For this *exact* example? As in most servers the default searched file is `index.*` when a website is loaded.

Comment: The DirectoryIndex works, if I just go to / index.php will be loaded, but I can access index.php as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depends which server you are using:

for `nginx`, check the following url:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html

for `apache` lookup DirectoryIndex. You need something like:

`DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm`

*Updating answer based on comments and update question*

Try this: Create a .htaccess file in your root directory with following content:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry for not specifying the server (my question is edited now), I'm using apache.

The DirectoryIndex works, if I just go to / index.php will be loaded, but I can access index.php as well.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment. Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled for your apache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't work, fully, though. An URL like:
http://www.example.com/index.php?a=b will be rewritten to http://www.example.com/?a=b

I only want to rewrite the exact /index.php (without query strings etc.) URL.

Answer (score 0):

Small trick

add this in your index.php

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="/index.php")
        header("location:http://www.example.com");
?>
```

what happens is $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] returns your current url in URL BAR so if it's /index.php redirect it to your domain without /index.php

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'd rather not dabble around with the index.php-file since I just installed this (so-so) code.